# current sensing with DRV8832 motor driver

Tags: current-measurement, motor-controller, current-limiting

I have designed a circuit which uses a TI DRV8832 motor driver but I m stuck in point of current sensing on motor driver. actually it is clear at Datasheet; DRV8832 has 1.3A peak Current and Rsens(Sensing Resistor) is calculated with 200mv/Iset(mA units)and the Datasheet determines that Rsens is limited to 1ohm max. Problem begins at this point too because I m using a mini dc brushed motor which has max 70mA Current draw stucking the motor shaft and also I must be monitoring the Motor's stuck. I have found 2.8ohm value when calculating Rsesn = 200mv/Isesn(70mA here) with datasheet formula but as I said previously its value is limited to 1ohm therefore I cant find a reasonable value to the Rsens in order to sense the motor'stuck. dear you electronic gurus if you can give me advice about it, it would appreciated. Thanks in Advance! [image]

also TI DRV8832 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8832.pdf)

Comment: it seems minimum sensing current would be 200mA.

Comment: thank you for your comment. ok I see but I want to learn  are there any amplifier combination which reflects the current draw in motor side by amplify to Iset ?

Comment: Amplification is not a proper solution in this case. It will seriously affect the accuracy of current sensing circuitry and you shouldn't too.

Comment: ok. You tell the truth. it may be fault prone. do you have any motor driver idea with low current feedback for my situation ?

Comment: Can't you ground that Isense pin?

Comment: I think it s not reasonable method because the ground path will be have ~0.2 ohm therefore it will increase the current draw due to the formula. thanks

Comment: It seems the minimal low current sense for voltage regulation seems 200mA from TI motor driver ICs.

Comment: The real issue here is that the motor driver isn't meant for motors this small.  Likely you can use an in-bounds sense resistor with a *differential amplifier* across it feeding your own fault detect.  It is also possible that you could use a larger sense resistor than recommended, since the voltage drop would be less than anticipated by the chip designer, however in going against the data sheet recommendation you would have to thoroughly investigate the situation to understand how it behaves in practice.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your advice! I m currently investigating to amplify a voltage accros Rsens by a certain gain so that I m planing to measure the Vsens with ADC peripheral of a MCU.  I will use  max 1 ohm Rsens accordingly Datasheet so that I will be able to read voltage between 0-70mv and I will amplfy it to 30 times. I hope it will solve the problem.